# Is there anyway to run multiple timers at the same time and stop the timer when a specific event occurs?

Tags: python, timer, discord.py, repeat

I want to program a bot that pings the user every 3 hours from the user starting their timer until the timer stops (which will be run by another command).
For example, if A started their timer at 5am UTC and B started their timer 1 hour after, A will be pinged at 8am UTC and B will be pinged at 9am UTC. This pinging process will repeat every 3 hours until the user decides to turn off their timer. So if A turned off their timer at 9am UTC and B didn't turn off their timer, A will not be pinged after a few hours, only B will be pinged until they decide to turn their timer off too.

Tried `while` statments, but it made the bot run slower and slower. And there will be a few people maybe a few thousand people running these timers at the same time.

Is there anyway to run this concept in a efficient way??

Below I pasted the code that I tried.

```
studying_now = []

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    command = message.content.split(' ')

    #start timer
    if command[0] == (f'{prefix}start'):
        try:
            #getting the user's timezone set
            timezone = timezoneDatabase[str(message.author.id)][0].split(':')

            #calculating the user's local time
            hours = int(timezone[0])
            minutes = int(timezone[1])
            utcTime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            hours_added = datetime.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes)
            calculated_time = (utcTime + hours_added).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            
            #checking if the user already started their timer
            if data.getStartTime(str(message.author)) != False: #tries getting the start time from Google Sheets, if returns False there is no start time logged.
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title='Timer started', 
                    description=f'<@{message.author.id}> Your timer has already started!', 
                    color=0x8f6c54
                )
                await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            elif data.logStartTime(message.author, calculated_time) == 'ok': #logging start time to Google Sheets, will return 'ok' if successfully run
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title='Timer started', 
                    description=f'<@{message.author.id}> Your timer has started counting!', 
                    color=0x8f6c54
                )
                await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

                channel = client.get_channel(877932875566153789) #get notification channel
                studying_now.append(message.author.id) #value will be removed when the user runs the stop command

                while message.author.id in studying_now:
                    await channel.send(f"<@{message.author.id}> Your timer is running!")
                    time.sleep(10800)
```

Comment: You havent really added any of your code running the loops, only the code that checks if the user started it or not, pretty hard to optimise code you don't give

Comment: What loop do you mean? I was asking if there was a efficient way as I tried using the while statment and it made the bot slower... and no ideas come up

Comment: Yet you provide no use of your exact implementation of that while loop

Comment: I pasted the code I used before now. Sorry..

Comment: Your issue is not in unoptimised code at all, you use time.sleep() to make your program sleep for a long time, time.sleep() not an asynchronous function, so it will stop your whole program from running at all(its called a `blocking` function, worth to read up on). What you need to use is `await asyncio.sleep(10800)`.

Comment: Oh thank you so much!